# Can't export a workflow from portal_setup

Tags: plone, plone-3.x

I've created a new workflow in `portal_workflow` (let's name it `my_workflow`), and I'm trying to export it using `portal_setup` without success. I've done this in the past with other workflows, and it worked like a charm. But, somehow, this last workflow I created can't be exported.

When exported, the new created workflow is presented in `workflows.xml`, but `workflows/my_workflow/` and `workflows/my_workflow/definition.xml` doesn't exist. The other workflows (including some custom ones) are exported.

Is there anything I'm unaware of that is preventing to export my new workflow? `portal_catalog`, something?

**EDIT**: I get this error when trying to extract the files. Is this something correlated? Just `my_workflow` isn't presented in my tar.gz.

```
gzip: stdin: invalid compressed data--length error
tar: Skipping to next header
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the problem relies in having non-ascii characters on *any* field (title, description, whatever) in your workflow definition.

I did some debugging in `eggs/Products.DCWorkflow-2.1.2-py2.4.egg/Products/DCWorkflow/exportimport.py` and `eggs/Products.GenericSetup-1.4.5-py2.4.egg/Products/GenericSetup/utils.py`, it exports `my_workflow` correctly, but the exported tar.gz had errors in the end.

When I removed all non-ascii characters from the workflows, the export went without errors, and `workflows/my_workflow` was present.

Anyone knows why is this? Am I correct in my assumptions?

Comment: I wasn't aware of this, but Zope2 / CMF tech has never been very good with non-ASCII characters in ZMI-level stuff. You could file a [bug in the project tracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/zope-cmf), with as simple a reproducible case as you can come up with.